# glob.glob and gdal_translate not working

Tags: python, gdal

I have a problem with my python script. I wrote it to convert MODIS data from .hdf into .tif. It will convert all files in a folder using a loop. I do not know which command I must enter to assume the files from the folder as input file. I tried *.hdf but then I got errors indicating that the file doesn´t exist.

The output-name of the new .tif should be the input name of the .hdf. At this point in my script it doesn´t work for me. I have no idea what I have to write now in the "gdal_translate"-command. I tried it with *.tif but this doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import glob
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr 
from osgeo import osr 
from osgeo import gdal_array 
from osgeo import gdalconst 
from osgeo.gdalconst import *

path = ''
path = raw_input('Directory? (z.B. C:\Daten\Modis\):')

# change to path
os.chdir( path )

# checks directory
vcheck = os.getcwd()

file = glob.glob('*.hdf')

for file in glob.glob('*.hdf'):

os.system('gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 "HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"*.hdf":MODIS_Grid_8Day_Fire:FireMask" *.tif')
```

Comment: Are there any errors reported?  If so what?

Comment: @kyle

Input file size is 1200, 1200

0ERROR 1: TIFFOpen:*.tif: No error

Input file size is 1200, 1200

0ERROR 1: TIFFOpen:*.tif: No error

Input file size is 1200, 1200

0ERROR 1: TIFFOpen:*.tif: No error

Input file size is 1200, 1200

0ERROR 1: TIFFOpen:*.tif: No error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues in the script. If you're new to Python I'd strongly recommend the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) and starting there.

The big issue was that it appears that you're trying to set your input and output filenames to a wildcard (the *.tif).

Additionally since you're running GDAL from the command prompt through `os.system` you don't need to import the osgeo libraries (but make sure that the GDAL bin directory is on your system PATH).

Lastly, `file` is a [built in type](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#file), so it's not a good idea to use it as a variable name.

Instead try the following using [string formatting operations](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import os.path
import glob

path = raw_input('Directory? (z.B. C:\Daten\Modis\):')

# change to path
os.chdir( path )

for f in glob.glob('*.hdf'):
    os.system('gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:4326 "HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:%s:MODIS_Grid_8Day_Fire:FireMask" %s.tif' % (f, os.path.basename(f)))
```